# Add $_GET-vars to a rewritten URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have several URLs which are dealt with by rewrite rules. Basically I want to add some $_GET-vars to a rewritten URL.

Say I have:

`http://www.domain.com/search/the-netherlands/overijssel/`

I would like to add some extra data to the URL like:

`http://www.domain.com/search/the-netherlands/overijssel/?custom_var=1`

My RewriteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/$    /index.php?page=Search&Country=$1&Region=$2 [L]
```

When I `var_dump` the contents of `$_GET` I don't see `custom_var` anywhere. Can this be done, using the existing rewrite rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query already has some parameters, append `[QSA]` to the end of the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/$    /index.php?page=Search&Country=$1&Region=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You don't want a space between `QSA,` and `L`, mod_rewrite will interpret those as different parameters.

Comment: I saw the space resulted in an error. I've removed the space and it works. Thanks +1 and accepted. For anyone else: here's a handy list: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Formatting woes. Thanks for the edit anubhava. And thanks Ben.